# How to access device boot menu on ASUS EeeBook x205ta?

Tags: eee-pc, asus-laptop

I am trying to boot a linux live usb on Asus x205ta but whatever Fx keys I push nothing comes out and I keep booting into windows.

How do I access the menu where I can choose the device to boot from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Restart** Windows. Not shutdown!
2. Read the ... manual! It can be found [here](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_EeeBook_X205TA/HelpDesk_Manual/).

[image]